# Neural net learning only one class?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I have setup a four layer CNN designed to predict two classes. The two classes are more or less in the same ratio. The negative class is 55% of the data and the positive class makes up the remaining. When I train the network on the data and look at the final results, I see two problems:

1. The validation accuracy fluctuates. In fact, it can be thought of as oscillating. The validation loss increases and the accuracy however keeps hovering.
2. The final results indicate a possible reason for this behaviour. The negative classes are very well classified. However, the postive classes are very poorly classified.

My question is why is the network exhbiting this behaviour. I've enough training data, ~10k images in training, and the classes are more or less balanced (5400 in the negative and 4500 in the positive). The issue raised in point 2 increases with an increase in the number of epochs. I've tried decreasing the learning rate, different optimizers, increased the number of layers, decreased the number of layers, used transfer learning (VGG-16). I've also tried reducing the number of epochs, but this leads to poor classification in the negative class as well.

Comment: Can you edit and update the form in which you are giving your labels to the network. Please provide a sample, also if possible provide the accuracy metrics you calculated i.e. precision, recall and F-score. Thanks.

Comment: How many parameters does your model have?

Comment: @HimanshuRai Sorry, I did not understand what you meant by updating the form.

Comment: Your labels are a one hot vector right?

Comment: No, I am not using one hot vectors. Should I be using them? @JanvanderVegt My model has four convolutional layers with ReLu activations, followed by a FC layer on top.

Comment: Yes, use one hot vectors and train again. To get the prediction take tf.argmax. Train like this once and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I get this error. Exception: Error when checking model target: expected activation_6 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (9940, 2). My last layer uses a sigmoid activation on top of the FC layer. I used one-hot encoding and followed this link [https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html].

Comment: @HimanshuRai I tried using one-hot encoding. Did not work. I think one-hot encoding will not work with binary_crossentropy, since the the final Dense layer will have only one neuron, which causes the error mentioned in the previous comment. I tried to correct for this using the categorical_crossentropy loss function, but no luck.

Comment: How bad is the accuracy for your positive classes?

Comment: I am getting NaNs for the loss after 10 epochs. So, can't really tell.